# Uncaught TypeError: i[e] is not a function frontend.min.js elementor

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I am having this error:
`webpack.runtime.min.js?ver=3.12.0:2 Uncaught TypeError: i[e] is not a function     at __webpack_require__ (webpack.runtime.min.js?ver=3.12.0:2:153)     at 5654 (frontend.min.js?ver=3.12.0:2:3475)`

I have updated elementor and I am having some issues to open photo galleries

I did update the elementor plugin
I tried to add an older version of it (worked till now)